# How can I save a image from photo library to app's documents folder

Tags: ios, swift

I'd like to let the user choose a photo from device photo library and then save it to the app's documents folder. Right now I can get the photo from the library but how can I save it in documents folder with its original name? All the answer I found online will require a new name for it. But I don't want to change its extension.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What "original name" are we talking about? Photos in the photo library have no name.

Comment: this code is working fine :::
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    guard let fileUrl = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.imageURL] as? URL else { return }
    print("Image name", fileUrl.lastPathComponent) // image name
    print(fileUrl.pathExtension)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

Comment: @matt, Oh that's new to me. So I will just assign a name to it and save? But how can I handle the filename extension? THanks

Answer (score 0):

you can get image name from this method after selecting the image.

```
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    guard let fileUrl = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.imageURL] as? URL else { return }
    print("Image name", fileUrl.lastPathComponent) // image name
    print(fileUrl.pathExtension)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```